# How to return full json using Manual ObjectID reference with Morphia

Tags: java, json, mongodb, morphia

Normally i use this:

```
public class Person {
...
@ID ObjectId id;
String name;

@Reference User user;
...
}
```

and it store the $ref and objectId of the user... and when i request i get the json

```
 Person {
         id...
         User { 
               login:
               password:
               }
         }
```

but "they" say to not use @Reference, to use the Manual Reference storing

so instead of @Referente to use something like ObjectId userID;

but if i use this, how can i build the json to return the full User? since i cant do something `person.setUser(userFromDataBaseByStoredReferenceId);`

or i really have to work using 2 attbrs in the class, one for storing the ID of the user, and another "User user", so i can set it and create the full json?

something like:

```
public class Person {
...
@ID ObjectId id;
String name;

ObjectId userID;
User user; //so i have to fill this to build the full json, after doing a extra search by the userID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Who is "they"? It will depend on your use case:

- `@Reference` eagerly loads all referenced entities by default. If you always need all of this data, this is the right approach.
- If you don't need all the (referenced) data most of the time, you can add the `lazy` attribute to the reference annotation. It will only load the data if you are actually accessing it.
- If you have very big entities and rarely need to traverse entities, you can roll your own reference approach by simply adding the ObjectId of a user. However, you will need to issue a query for that yourself and you cannot access it like `person.getUser()` any longer.

PS: Your JSON example looks a bit like an embedded entity. Maybe this is a better approach for your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a @PostLoad method to load the referenced entity by its id.

```
@PostLoad
void postLoad() {
  this.user = UserDAO.get(userID);
}
```